# React form actions > Edit, Save, Remove, Cancel

Tags: javascript, beginner, react.js, jsx

For my robot hobby project I need to expose the system's configuration so I can quickly make changes to it. So I have made a very simple app that generates a form. In this form you can edit, save fields, cancel edits or remove a module from the configuration.

I wrote this with no prior knowledge of JS and React. But I did not just sit down and monkey out some code. I researched and studied how to do this, and it is working. I am happy with it, and the code is the best I can produce.

You can copy this code and play with the form to see how it works.

`configForm.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import FieldsetList from './fieldsetList'

//this will be sent via and endpoint or via ws
var configuration = {
  cameras: {
    USB_Camera_1: {
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
      device_path: '/dev/video1',
      pixel_format: 'yuy420p',
      input_format: 'h264',
      framerate: '30',
      segmented: true,
      name: 'USB_Camera_1',
      segment_time: '360',
      output_path: '/home/user/Desktop/video',
      mode: 2
    },
    USB_Camera_2: {
      width: 640,
      height: 480,
      device_path: '/dev/video2',
      pixel_format: 'yuy420p',
      input_format: 'h264',
      framerate: '30',
      segmented: true,
      name: 'USB_Camera_2',
      segment_time: '360',
      output_path: '/home/user/Desktop/video',
      mode: 2
    }
  },
  disk_monitor: {
    limit: 10000,
    file_extension: '.mp4'
  },
  server: {
    port: ':5000',
    root_path: '/home/user/Desktop/video'
  },
  pir: {
    vin_pin: 23,
    gnd_pin: 21,
    output_pin: 25
  },
  light_sensor: {
    vin_pin: 24,
    gnd_pin: 22,
    output_pin: 26
  }
}

export default class ConfigForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = configuration
    this.dispatch = this.dispatch.bind(this)
  }

  //config will not have more than one single nested object
  //parentKey passed for identifying top level object, if any, when dispatching an action
  dispatch = (state, parentKey, action) => {
    switch (action) {
      case 'save':
        if (parentKey != '') {
          newState = this.state
          newState[parentKey][Object.keys(state)[0]] = state
          this.setState(newState)
          return
        }
        //also will be written to file
        this.setState(state)
        return
      case 'remove':
        var newState = this.state

        if (parentKey != '') {
          delete newState[parentKey][Object.keys(state)[0]]

          this.setState(newState)
          return
        }

        delete newState[Object.keys(state)[0]]

        //also will be written to file
        this.setState(newState)
        return
    }
  }

  render() {
    let { cameras = {}, ...modules } = this.state
    let list = [
      <FieldsetList
        key={0}
        dispatch={this.dispatch}
        parentKey="cameras"
        modules={cameras}
      />,
      <FieldsetList
        key={1}
        dispatch={this.dispatch}
        parentKey=""
        modules={modules}
      />
    ]
    return list
  }
}
```

`fieldsetList.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Fieldset from './fieldset.js'

const FieldsetList = props => {
  let list = []

  Object.keys(props.modules).map(key => {
    list.push(
      <Fieldset
        key={key}
        moduleName={key}
        parentKey={props.parentKey}
        dispatch={props.dispatch}
        module={props.modules[key]}
      />
    )
  })

  return <div>{list}</div>
}

FieldsetList.propTypes = {
  parentKey: PropTypes.string,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func,
  modules: PropTypes.object
}

export default FieldsetList
```

`fieldSet.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Input, Button, Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class Fieldset extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.module = this.props.moduleName

    this.state = {
      [this.props.moduleName]: this.props.module,
      ctrls: {
        fieldsetDisabled: true,
        fieldsetBtn: 'edit',
        fieldsetBtnHandler: () => {
          this.edit()
        },
        hideCancelBtn: true,
        dropDownDisabled: true
      },
      dropdownOptions: [],
      remove: {}
    }

    //cancel event handler uses this state for resetting form
    this.baseState = {}

    //button event handlers
    this.inputChange = this.inputChange.bind(this)
    this.edit = this.edit.bind(this)
    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this)
    this.save = this.save.bind(this)
    this.cancel = this.cancel.bind(this)
  }

  //system will check for available modules and send via ws
  //dropdown options and module remove attributes
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.setState({
      dropdownOptions: [
        {
          key: 0,
          text: '/dev/video11',
          value: '/dev/video11'
        },
        {
          key: 1,
          text: '/dev/video12',
          value: '/dev/video12'
        },
        {
          key: 2,
          text: '/dev/video13',
          value: '/dev/video13'
        }
      ],
      remove: {
        USB_Camera_1: true,
        USB_Camera_2: true,
        pir: true,
        light_sensor: true,
        server: false,
        disk_monitor: false
      }
    })

    this.baseState = this.state
  }

  inputChange = e => {
    let field = e.currentTarget.name
    let value = e.currentTarget.value

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      [this.module]: {
        ...prevState[this.module],
        [field]: value
      }
    }))
  }

  edit = () => {
    this.setState({
      ctrls: {
        fieldsetBtn: 'save',
        fieldsetBtnHandler: () => {
          this.save()
        },
        cancelBtnHandler: () => {
          this.cancel()
        },
        removeBtnHandler: () => {
          this.remove()
        },
        fieldsetDisabled: false,
        hideCancelBtn: false,
        dropDownDisabled: false
      }
    })
  }

  save = () => {
    (async () => {
      await this.setState({
        ctrls: {
          fieldsetBtn: 'edit',
          fieldsetBtnHandler: () => {
            this.edit()
          },
          fieldsetDisabled: true,
          hideCancelBtn: true,
          dropDownDisabled: true
        }
      })

      this.baseState = this.state
    })()

    let module = {
      [this.module]: this.state[this.module]
    }

    this.props.dispatch(module, this.props.parentKey, 'save')
  }

  cancel = () => {
    this.setState(this.baseState)
  }

  remove = () => {
    let module = {
      [this.module]: null
    }

    this.props.dispatch(module, this.props.parentKey, 'remove')
  }

  inputType = value => {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(value))) {
      return 'text'
    } else {
      return 'number'
    }
  }

  generateInputs() {
    var inputs = []
    Object.keys(this.state[this.module]).map(inputKey => {
      let value = this.state[this.module][inputKey]

      switch (inputKey) {
        case 'device_path':
          inputs.push(
            <div key={inputKey}>
              <span>{inputKey}:</span>
              <Dropdown
                name={inputKey}
                placeholder={value}
                fluid
                selection
                options={this.state.dropdownOptions}
                disabled={this.state.ctrls.dropDownDisabled}
              />
            </div>
          )
          break
        default:
          inputs.push(
            <div key={inputKey}>
              <span>{inputKey}:</span>
              <Input
                type={this.inputType(value)}
                name={inputKey}
                value={value}
                onChange={this.inputChange}
              />
            </div>
          )
      }
    })
    return inputs
  }

  render() {
    const cancelBtnStyle = this.state.ctrls.hideCancelBtn
      ? { display: 'none' }
      : {}

    let removeBtn = (
      <Button
        key={1}
        content="remove"
        onClick={this.state.ctrls.removeBtnHandler}
        type="button"
      />
    )

    const showRemoveBtn = this.state.remove[this.module] ? removeBtn : null

    let elements = [
      <fieldset key={0} disabled={this.state.ctrls.fieldsetDisabled}>
        <legend>{this.module}</legend>
        {this.generateInputs()}
        {showRemoveBtn}
      </fieldset>,

      <Button
        key={2}
        content={this.state.ctrls.fieldsetBtn}
        onClick={this.state.ctrls.fieldsetBtnHandler}
        type="button"
      />,

      <Button
        key={3}
        content="cancel"
        onClick={this.state.ctrls.cancelBtnHandler}
        style={cancelBtnStyle}
        type="button"
      />
    ]

    return elements
  }
}

Fieldset.propTypes = {
  parentKey: PropTypes.string,
  moduleName: PropTypes.string,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func,
  module: PropTypes.object
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last component looks quite complicated. I think some refactoring would help with readability but I have no concrete suggestions since I don't really understand what it's doing. Like this here `this.state.remove[this.module]`.
in the comments
I wrote some advice in the comments. Hopefully it's understandable. I mention direct state mutations a couple of times. You can find [more information here](https://jkettmann.com/how-to-accidentally-mutate-state-and-why-not-to/).

configForm.js

```js
export default class ConfigForm extends React.Component {
  // binding dispatch is not necessary since you use an arrow function
  // thus the constructor is not required anymore
  state = configuration

  // too me calling this function dispatch and having an action of type string
  // is confusing. The dispatch keyword is somewhat occupied by useReducer or Redux
  dispatch = (state, parentKey, action) => {
    switch (action) {
      case 'save':
        if (parentKey != '') {
          // this is doing nothing, just assigning the state to another variable
          // not to confuse with creating a new object
          // additionally this looks like a syntax error since newState is not defined (var missing?)
          newState = this.state
          // here you're changing the state object directly which is not recommended
          // see my blog post below
          newState[parentKey][Object.keys(state)[0]] = state
          this.setState(newState)
          // rather use else statement for readability IMO
          return
        }
        // see above, rather use else IMO
        this.setState(state)
        // use break instead
        return
      case 'remove':
        var newState = this.state

        if (parentKey != '') {
          // again mutating state directly
          delete newState[parentKey][Object.keys(state)[0]]

          this.setState(newState)
          // again else statement instead
          return
        }

        // again mutating state directly
        delete newState[Object.keys(state)[0]]

        //also will be written to file
        this.setState(newState)
        return
    }
  }

  render() {
    let { cameras = {}, ...modules } = this.state
    let list = [
      <FieldsetList
        key={0}
        dispatch={this.dispatch}
        parentKey="cameras"
        modules={cameras}
      />,
      <FieldsetList
        key={1}
        dispatch={this.dispatch}
        parentKey=""
        modules={modules}
      />
    ]
    // you're not iterating over this array so I would suggest
    // to use a fragment <>...your FieldsetLists</>
    return list
  }
}
```

refactored fieldsetList.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Fieldset from './fieldset.js'

const FieldsetList = props => (
  <div>
    {
      // map already returns an array, no need for push
      Object.keys(props.modules).map(key => (
        <Fieldset
          key={key}
          moduleName={key}
          parentKey={props.parentKey}
          dispatch={props.dispatch}
          module={props.modules[key]}
        />
      ))
    }
  </div>
)

FieldsetList.propTypes = {
  parentKey: PropTypes.string,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func,
  modules: PropTypes.object
}

export default FieldsetList
```

fieldSet.js

````js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Input, Button, Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class Fieldset extends React.Component {
  // constructor can be removed again
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // not sure why you use the class variable here
    // in most cases this is a code smell IMO
    this.module = this.props.moduleName

    this.state = {
      [this.props.moduleName]: this.props.module,
      ctrls: {
        fieldsetDisabled: true,
        fieldsetBtn: 'edit',
        // I don't think you should have a function inside the state
        // especially one that's practically not doing anything
        fieldsetBtnHandler: () => {
          this.edit()
        },
        hideCancelBtn: true,
        dropDownDisabled: true
      },
      dropdownOptions: [],
      remove: {}
    }


    this.baseState = {}

    // again not needed since you use arrow functions
    this.inputChange = this.inputChange.bind(this)
    this.edit = this.edit.bind(this)
    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this)
    this.save = this.save.bind(this)
    this.cancel = this.cancel.bind(this)
  }

  // componentDidMount is not async
  async componentDidMount() {
    // setState doesn't return a promise so you should use await on it
    // if you need to do something as soon as the state is updated
    // use the setState callback parameter (the second I think) 
    await this.setState({
      dropdownOptions: [
        {
          key: 0,
          text: '/dev/video11',
          value: '/dev/video11'
        },
        {
          key: 1,
          text: '/dev/video12',
          value: '/dev/video12'
        },
        {
          key: 2,
          text: '/dev/video13',
          value: '/dev/video13'
        }
      ],
      remove: {
        USB_Camera_1: true,
        USB_Camera_2: true,
        pir: true,
        light_sensor: true,
        server: false,
        disk_monitor: false
      }
    })

    // not sure why you do this but it smells
    this.baseState = this.state
  }

  inputChange = e => {
    let field = e.currentTarget.name
    let value = e.currentTarget.value

    // this looks fine form a mutation perspective
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      // why not just use this.props.moduleName
      [this.module]: {
        ...prevState[this.module],
        [field]: value
      }
    }))
  }

  edit = () => {
    this.setState({
      ctrls: {
        fieldsetBtn: 'save',
        // again functions in state seem odd
        fieldsetBtnHandler: () => {
          this.save()
        },
        cancelBtnHandler: () => {
          this.cancel()
        },
        removeBtnHandler: () => {
          this.remove()
        },
        fieldsetDisabled: false,
        hideCancelBtn: false,
        dropDownDisabled: false
      }
    })
  }

  save = () => {
    // again setState is not returning a promise
    (async () => {
      await this.setState({
        ctrls: {
          fieldsetBtn: 'edit',
          fieldsetBtnHandler: () => {
            this.edit()
          },
          fieldsetDisabled: true,
          hideCancelBtn: true,
          dropDownDisabled: true
        }
      })

      this.baseState = this.state
    })()

    let module = {
      [this.module]: this.state[this.module]
    }

    // I think it would increase readability if you used separate functions
    // for save, remove etc instead of abstracting them with dispatch
    this.props.dispatch(module, this.props.parentKey, 'save')
  }

  cancel = () => {
    this.setState(this.baseState)
  }

  remove = () => {
    let module = {
      [this.module]: null
    }

    this.props.dispatch(module, this.props.parentKey, 'remove')
  }

  inputType = value => {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(value))) {
      return 'text'
    } else {
      return 'number'
    }
  }

  generateInputs() {
    var inputs = []
    // again no need for pushing since map returns an array
    Object.keys(this.state[this.module]).map(inputKey => {
      let value = this.state[this.module][inputKey]

      switch (inputKey) {
        case 'device_path':
          inputs.push(
            <div key={inputKey}>
              <span>{inputKey}:</span>
              <Dropdown
                name={inputKey}
                placeholder={value}
                fluid
                selection
                options={this.state.dropdownOptions}
                disabled={this.state.ctrls.dropDownDisabled}
              />
            </div>
          )
          break
        default:
          inputs.push(
            <div key={inputKey}>
              <span>{inputKey}:</span>
              <Input
                type={this.inputType(value)}
                name={inputKey}
                value={value}
                onChange={this.inputChange}
              />
            </div>
          )
      }
    })
    return inputs
  }

  render() {
    const cancelBtnStyle = this.state.ctrls.hideCancelBtn
      ? { display: 'none' }
      : {}

    let removeBtn = (
      <Button
        key={1}
        content="remove"
        onClick={this.state.ctrls.removeBtnHandler}
        type="button"
      />
    )

    const showRemoveBtn = this.state.remove[this.module] ? removeBtn : null

    // rather use a fragment, it's not common to return an array
    let elements = [
      <fieldset key={0} disabled={this.state.ctrls.fieldsetDisabled}>
        <legend>{this.module}</legend>
        {this.generateInputs()}
        {showRemoveBtn}
      </fieldset>,

      <Button
        key={2}
        content={this.state.ctrls.fieldsetBtn}
        onClick={this.state.ctrls.fieldsetBtnHandler}
        type="button"
      />,

      <Button
        key={3}
        content="cancel"
        onClick={this.state.ctrls.cancelBtnHandler}
        style={cancelBtnStyle}
        type="button"
      />
    ]

    return elements
  }
}

Fieldset.propTypes = {
  parentKey: PropTypes.string,
  moduleName: PropTypes.string,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func,
  module: PropTypes.object
}
```
````

Comment: Hello friend. What great feedback, thanks. I have only one point where I am scratching my head, hope you can provide more feedback on it. It is concerning the `fieldsetBtnHandler` in the `ctrls` object. That's the onClick handler func for button with key 2 and its initial state is `edit`. Once clicked it's function will be replaced with `save` unless cancelled by the cancel button. Having the handler in the state is the only way I can think of assigning a new handler for the button once clicked. Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: also, just for clarification, `this.state.remove[this.module]` is just really bad naming from me. It refers to modules that are allowed to be removed from config as they are not core modules and the robot can go on without them. Maybe a better name would be `can_be_removed`